# How do I make a 0-9 dropdown menu in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This is a really rookie question - but anyway .. What is the best way to make a 0-9 dropdown menu? Said another way - How do I make a dropdown menu containing the values [0, 1, 2, 3... 9] and the default value should be 0..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference you should probably provide some code of what you've attempted. Here's my solution:

javascript:

```
$scope.options = [];
for(var x = 0; x < 10; x++){
    $scope.options.push(x);
}
$scope.selectedOption = 0;
```

html

```
 <select data-ng-model="selectedOption" data-ng-options="option as option for option in options"></select>
```

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/mujem4zf/

Answer (score 0):

Just use [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) to define the options of your select input:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <select ng-options="o for o in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]" ng-model="myValue" ng-init="myValue=0"></select>
  <br />Selected value: {{myValue}}
</div>
```